# Add onClick event to document.createElement("th")

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am dynamically adding columns to a table by using `document.createElement("th")`

```
var newTH = document.createElement('th');
```

Is there a way to set an `onClick` attribute for this so a user can delete the column by clicking on the header? Any help would be great. If this is not possible, is it possible to put something in

```
newTH.innerHTML
```

to make it work?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

```
var newTH = document.createElement('th');
newTH.innerHTML = 'Hello, World!';
newTH.onclick = function () {
    this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
};

var table = document.getElementById('content');
table.appendChild(newTH);
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/23tBM/

You can also just hide with `this.style.display = 'none'`.

Comment: this successfully removes the header, any idea how to also remove the cells beneath it?

Comment: @daniellanger That gets more complicated.

Comment: Can I somehow append the element like this?
`var html = "my dynamic element"+newTH+"WOW!"; other_el.innerHTML = html;`

Comment: I think when/the reason many end up on this page is when/because THIS does NOT work for whatever reason. ...

Answer (score 17):

```
var newTH = document.createElement('th');
newTH.setAttribute("onclick", "removeColumn(#)");
newTH.setAttribute("id", "#");

function removeColumn(#){
// remove column #
}
```

Answer (score 15):

```
var newTH = document.createElement('th');
newTH.onclick = function() {
      //Your code here
}
```

Comment: thanks, that creates the event! any ideas as to a simple way to hide that element within the function? It doesn't have an ID or class which makes it a bit difficult

Answer (score 10):

```
var newTH = document.createElement('th');
newTH.addEventListener( 'click', function(){
  // delete the column here
} );
```