# Create element from HTML but pass a function as a handle

Tags: javascript, dom

```
function createResendIVButton(userId, name){
    return '<span class=btn onclick=usersTable.resendInvestorVerification("'+userId+'","'+name+'")>resend&nbsp;I.V.</span>';
}
```

When creating an element as HTML, is it possible to somehow send the function handle instead of a string (function name)? String is inconvenient, because of visibility problems. And I need to create from HTML because library I use do not let me access its DOM easily, but allows me to initialize rows from HTML code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add onClick event to document.createElement("th")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017509/add-onclick-event-to-document-createelementth)

Comment: @rishipuri your reference suggests use of `appendChild()`, but I can only send HTML code to some function.

Comment: have you tried using `eval()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Creates a DOM element and bind on then a action:

```
        function createResendIVButton(userId, name){

            var button = document.createElement('span');
            button.className = 'btn';

            button.addEventListener('click', function(){

                console.log(userId);
                console.log(name);

            });

            button.innerHTML = 'click on me';

            return button;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```js
function createResendIVButton(userId, name) {
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = 'resend I.V';
  span.onclick = function() {
    usersTable.resendInvestorVerfication(userId, name);
  }
  
  var div = document.getElementById('somecontent');
  div.appendChild(span);
}


createResendIVButton(1, 'Joe');
```

```css
#somecontent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
 }
```

```html
<div id='somecontent'>
</div>
```