# Separating input values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RgQOWz

It has increment/decrement and it does what I want, but the problem is they both change together and I want to separate counter 1 from counter 2 meaning if I want to change counter 1 values it doesn't have to effect counter 2 and vice versa.

I can basically give counter 2 different class names and write another script for it but that is a lot of work considering the counters will be many.

so how do I do this?

Javascript code

```
$(".increment").click(function() {
  var score1 = $(".score").val();
  score1++;
  $(".score").val(score1);
});

$(".decrement").click(function() {
  var score1 = $(".score").val();
  if (score1 == 0) {
  } else {
    score1--;
    $(".score").val(score1);
  }
});
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but your code has duplicate IDs. You'll want to remedy that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you JavaScript to this

```
$(".increment").click(function() {

  var score1 = $(this).next().find('.score').val();
  score1++;
  $($(this).next().find('.score').val(score1));
});

$(".decrement").click(function() {
  var score1 = $(this).prev().find('.score').val();
  if (score1 == 0) {
  } else {
    score1--;
    $(this).prev().find('.score').val(score1);
  }
});
```

instead of setting value to .score find the score based on which increment or decrement selection was selected

here is a working codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xrYoRr#anon-login

Answer (score 1):

Both counters using elements with the same `.score` class to keep the score. So each element updates both `.score`. You should either use IDs instead of classes, or (preferably) dynamically create elements and assign behaviors directly.

For example:

- [Add onClick event to document.createElement("th")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017509/add-onclick-event-to-document-createelementth)
- [jQuery how to bind onclick event to dynamically added HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525664/jquery-how-to-bind-onclick-event-to-dynamically-added-html-element)

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to your code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="row end-xs">      
      <div class="row middle-xs">
          <p>Counter1</p>
      </div>       
      <div class="prdin">
        <div class="increment-c1">
          <i class="icon-arrow-up icons"></i>
        </div>
        <div id="input1">
          <input type="number" class="score1" value="0">
        </div>
        <div class="decrement-c1">
          <i class="icon-arrow-down icons"></i>
        </div>
      </div>   
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="row start-xs">
      <div class="prdin">
        <div class="increment-c2">
          <i class="icon-arrow-up icons"></i>
        </div>
        <div id="input2">
          <input type="number" class="score2" value="0">
        </div>
        <div class="decrement-c2">
          <i class="icon-arrow-down icons"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row middle-xs">
          <p>Counter2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And javascript code as below:

```
$(".increment-c1").click(function() {
  var score1 = $(".score1").val();
  score1++;
  $(".score1").val(score1);
});

$(".decrement-c1").click(function() {
  var score1 = $(".score1").val();
  if (score1 == 0) {
  } else {
    score1--;
    $(".score1").val(score1);
  }
});
$(".increment-c2").click(function() {
  var score1 = $(".score2").val();
  score1++;
  $(".score2").val(score1);
});

$(".decrement-c2").click(function() {
  var score1 = $(".score2").val();
  if (score1 == 0) {
  } else {
    score1--;
    $(".score2").val(score1);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your work, but I have said in op that I can do that way and so the counters can be as many as 20, so this solution won't help.

Comment: ok. @Karthik Ganesan's answer has solved the problem. I guess.