# How can i make my second button have an onclick function

Tags: html, button, dom-events

I created a button where when clicked on creates another button but Iam not sure how to make an onclick event for that button

```
function boyFunction(){
    var btn1 = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var x = document.createTextNode("basketball");
    btn1.appendChild(x);
    document.body.appendChild(btn1);
    btn1.classList.add('btn1');
}
```

I want to be able to click the basketball button and have that button show an image

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017509/add-onclick-event-to-document-createelementth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things had to be done.

First your new element will need an id

```
btn1.setAttribute("id", "myButton");
```

click event handler will need to be created for your new element

```
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", myButtonClickHandler);
```

and then you will define your click handler in a new function

```
function myButtonClickHandler {
// my code
}
```

Your code after doing the above change will look like below:

```
function boyFunction(){
    var btn1 = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    btn1.setAttribute("id", "myButton");
    var x = document.createTextNode("basketball");
    btn1.appendChild(x);
    document.body.appendChild(btn1);
    btn1.classList.add('btn1');

    document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", myButtonClickHandler); 
}

function myButtonClickHandler {
// my code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an Click Handler like this:

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
   alert("button was clicked");
}​;​
```

of course you need to give your new button the id 'button' or any other id you choose

Answer (score 0):

Can work like this:

```
function boyFunction(){
    var btn1 = document.createElement("BUTTON");

    // your "onclick function" goes here
    btn1.onclick = function () { };

    var x = document.createTextNode("basketball");
    btn1.appendChild(x);
    document.body.appendChild(btn1);
    btn1.classList.add('btn1');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this

```
 function boyFunction(){
        var btn1 = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        btn1.addEventListener('click',()=>console.log('clicked'));
        var x = document.createTextNode("basketball");
        btn1.appendChild(x);
        document.body.appendChild(btn1);
        btn1.classList.add('btn1');
    }
```